# Why is it that when i run my code it says "AttributeError: Enemy instance has no attribute 'enemy'"?

Tags: python

my code can both be found and ran here : https://repl.it/Bda9/10

right now i'm focusing on the 'explore' then 'attack' pathways, but for some reason this code will not run a single attack. I need to get this at least working by tonight. We just started OOP and... well... this is frustrating me.

what is causing that error?
why does the code not recognize enemy (I think that's what the error means)?

Comment: In your code you didnt have any `enemy` attribute for `Character` class or `Enemy` class , how you try you access it?

Comment: The player has no `enemy` set on it.

Comment: but i created the enemy attribute inside of the player classs, why would't that work?

Comment: `Player` class is another class you should put `Enemy` attribute in `Character` class if you want to call it with out using `Player` class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you should try to [pare down your code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to a minimal example, so answerers don't have to do the work of locating the bug. You should also post the stack trace (repl.it provides it) so we can check the error we get is the same one you do.

You get an error in the `Enemy.enemy_attacks` method. Within this method, `self` refers to the `Enemy` object, and no longer to the `Player` object as it did in the method that called it. The attributes of the enemy, such as `attack`, are attributes of `self`, not of `self.enemy`; the `Enemy` object has no `enemy` attribute, hence the error when you try to access it.

Note also that within this method, the player is `p` (passed as an argument), not `self.p` (line 66; it could make sense to make the player an attribute of the enemy but you're not doing that) or `player` (line 69, probably just a typo).

Your difficulty seems to be with what `self` means. If this answer doesn't suffice to solve your problem, try editing the question to add your understanding of what you mean by `self`.